# Error in uploading large files > 1GB from SFTP to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, file-transfer, apache-mina

I am trying to upload files to s3 bucket directly from SFTP server. It works till 1GB and after that it gives error as shown below. I am using Apache MINA to set up the virtual directory and leaf node of directory structure is linked with s3 store. Below is the code.

```
public class FileRemotePathChannel extends FileChannel {

@Override
    public int write(ByteBuffer src) throws IOException {
        if (channel == null) {
            pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
            pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInputStream);
            channel = Channels.newChannel(pipedOutputStream);
            createS3Thread(this.bucketName);
        }
        log.info("Writing buffer with size :{} to s3", src);
        channel.write(src);
        return src.remaining();
    }

    private void createS3Thread(String bucketName) {
        if (s3WriteThread == null) {
            log.debug("Transfering file : {} to object store in bucket :{}", path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
                    bucketName);
            s3WriteThread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        getAmazonS3Instance().writeFileToBucket(bucketName, path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
                                pipedInputStream);
                        pipedInputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Error writing file to S3", e);
                    }
                }
            };
            s3WriteThread.start();
        }
    }
}



 public void writeFileToBucket(String bucket, String fileName, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            log.info("Uploading file to s3 bucket with bucketName :{}, fileName: {}", bucket, fileName);
            s3Connection.awsConnection().putObject(bucket, fileName, inputStream, metadata);
        }
```

Error log while uploading more than 1gb file:

```
2020-02-28 19:05:23.664 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting new position :0
2020-02-28 19:05:23.664 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting the position for Write
2020-02-28 19:05:23.664 INFO  com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Writing buffer with size :java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=57 lim=32761 cap=32825] to s3
2020-02-28 19:05:23.665 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:23.665 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.subsystem.sftp.SftpSubsystem - doSendStatus(ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705])[id=117493766] SSH_FXP_STATUS (substatus=SSH_FX_OK, lang=, msg=)
2020-02-28 19:05:23.666 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.subsystem.sftp.SftpSubsystem - process(ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705])[length=32757, type=SSH_FXP_WRITE, id=117494022] processing
2020-02-28 19:05:23.666 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.server.xyzSFTPEventListener - Session is Writing for offset :1073672320, dataoffset :57, and file size :32704
2020-02-28 19:05:23.666 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting new position :0
2020-02-28 19:05:23.666 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting the position for Write
2020-02-28 19:05:23.666 INFO  com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Writing buffer with size :java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=57 lim=32761 cap=32825] to s3
2020-02-28 19:05:23.666 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:23.666 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.subsystem.sftp.SftpSubsystem - doSendStatus(ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705])[id=117494022] SSH_FXP_STATUS (substatus=SSH_FX_OK, lang=, msg=)
2020-02-28 19:05:23.667 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.subsystem.sftp.SftpSubsystem - process(ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705])[length=32757, type=SSH_FXP_WRITE, id=117494278] processing
2020-02-28 19:05:23.667 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.server.xyzSFTPEventListener - Session is Writing for offset :1073705024, dataoffset :57, and file size :32704
2020-02-28 19:05:23.667 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting new position :0
2020-02-28 19:05:23.667 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting the position for Write
2020-02-28 19:05:23.667 INFO  com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Writing buffer with size :java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=57 lim=32761 cap=32825] to s3
2020-02-28 19:05:23.668 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:23.668 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.subsystem.sftp.SftpSubsystem - doSendStatus(ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705])[id=117494278] SSH_FXP_STATUS (substatus=SSH_FX_OK, lang=, msg=)
2020-02-28 19:05:23.668 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.subsystem.sftp.SftpSubsystem - process(ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705])[length=32757, type=SSH_FXP_WRITE, id=117494534] processing
2020-02-28 19:05:23.669 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.server.xyzSFTPEventListener - Session is Writing for offset :1073737728, dataoffset :57, and file size :32704
2020-02-28 19:05:23.669 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting new position :0
2020-02-28 19:05:23.669 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting the position for Write
2020-02-28 19:05:23.669 INFO  com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Writing buffer with size :java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=57 lim=32761 cap=32825] to s3
2020-02-28 19:05:23.670 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:23.671 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:23.673 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:23.675 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:23.677 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:23.678 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:23.680 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:24.040 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:24.041 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:24.041 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:24.042 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:24.042 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:24.042 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:24.043 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:24.043 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=32761
2020-02-28 19:05:24.043 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession - handleData(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=256]-ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705]) SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA len=448
2020-02-28 19:05:24.040 DEBUG com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient - FYI: failed to reset content inputstream before throwing up
java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:448) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkBufferedInputStream.reset(SdkBufferedInputStream.java:106) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:112) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.reset(ProgressInputStream.java:168) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:112) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.lastReset(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1072) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4319) [aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4266) [aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1746) [aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1608) [aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.232.jar:?]
    at com.sc.xyz.sshd.component.AmazonS3Component.writeFileToBucket(AmazonS3Component.java:96) [classes/:?]
    at com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel$1.run(FileRemotePathChannel.java:126) [classes/:?]
2020-02-28 19:05:24.670 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.subsystem.sftp.SftpSubsystem - doSendStatus(ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705])[id=117494534] SSH_FXP_STATUS (substatus=SSH_FX_FAILURE, lang=, msg=General failure)
2020-02-28 19:05:24.671 DEBUG org.apache.sshd.server.subsystem.sftp.SftpSubsystem - process(ServerSessionImpl[user1@/127.0.0.1:52705])[length=32757, type=SSH_FXP_WRITE, id=117494790] processing
2020-02-28 19:05:24.671 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.server.xyzSFTPEventListener - Session is Writing for offset :1073770432, dataoffset :57, and file size :32704
2020-02-28 19:05:24.671 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting new position :0
2020-02-28 19:05:24.671 DEBUG com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Setting the position for Write
2020-02-28 19:05:24.671 INFO  com.sc.xyz.sshd.filesystem.FileRemotePathChannel - Writing buffer with size :java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=57 lim=32761 cap=32825] to s3
```

Thing that i have tried to solve this is passing this value in java arguments -`Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.s3.defaultStreamBufferSize=5368709120` but the issue still persist.

Please let me know if any ideas or any solutions.